# How to explicitly take in certain templated inputs as arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have `Foo<a, b>` and `Foo<c, d>` where `Foo` takes in 2 templated parameters. If I have a variadic template with class `SomeFunction` that takes in those `Foo` inputs like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class SomeFunction< /*some input*/ >
```

What can I do to make sure `SomeFunction` only takes `Foo` templates and not some other template like `Blah<a,b>`?

Comment: At least to me, the intent of this Qn is not clear. Probably you can give some code example to clarify more for other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your type privately inherit from another type which cannot be instantiated unless the type arguments are correct.  You leave the template type undefined and then partially specialize for the `Foo<...>` case, recursing with the remainder of the list.

```
// Base template forward declaration, but note we don't define it.
template <typename...>
struct foo_validator;

// Specialization handling the terminating case.
template <>
struct foo_validator<> {};

// Partial specialization, handling Foo<a, b> followed by anything.  Note in particular
// how it inherits itself with the remainder of the type arguments.
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Tail>
struct foo_validator<Foo<T1, T2>, Tail...> : foo_validator<Tail...> {};

// Now have SomeFunction privately inherit this type.
template <typename ...Ts>
class SomeFunction : private foo_validator<Ts...> {};
```

If you pass any type arguments except `Foo<A, B>` (where `A` and `B` can be any type) then none of the specializations will match and the compiler will attempt to instantiate the unspecialized template.  Because it is not defined, this will cause a compilation error.

This declaration:

```
SomeFunction<Foo<int, float>, std::pair<short, double>> a;
```

Will fail with:

> `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct foo_validator<std::pair<short int, double> >'`

---

Another approach is very similar and uses `static_assert`:

```
// As before, this is the failing case, but we define it to inherit
// std::false_type.
template <typename...>
struct foo_validator : std::false_type {};

// The empty case is success and inherits std::true_type.
template <>
struct foo_validator<> : std::true_type {};

// Again, the "so-far-successful" partial specialization.
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Tail>
struct foo_validator<Foo<T1, T2>, Tail...> : foo_validator<Tail...> {};

// Instead of inheriting foo_validator, we assert on its value member.
template <typename ...Ts>
class SomeFunction {
    static_assert(foo_validator<Ts...>::value, "All type arguments must be Foo<,>");
};
```

Now a bad instantiation of `SomeFunction` will fail with:

> `error: static assertion failed: All type arguments must be Foo<,>`

---

How does this work?  We have three declarations in both approach, and they all fill the same roles in both:

1. We declare a template that accepts *any* type arguments as the failing case.
2. We declare a specialization of this template for the case where there are no type arguments as the successful case ([vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)).
3. We declare a partial specialization for when the first argument is an instantiation of the `Foo` template type with two type parameters, and then any number (zero or more) of other type parameters.  This type inherits the validator template type with the first type argument removed (recursion).

Let's look at an example where we try to instantiate `SomeFunction<Foo<int, int>, Foo<float, double>>`.

1. The compiler tries to instantiate `foo_validator<Foo<int, int>, Foo<float, double>>`. This matches the partial specialization, type 3 in the list above. (`T1 = int, T2 = int, Tail = [Foo<float, double>]`)  This type inherits `foo_validator<Foo<float, double>>`.
2. The compiler tries to instantiate `foo_validator<Foo<float, double>>`. This also matches the partial specialization, type 3 in the list above. (`T1 = float, T2 = double, Tail = []`)  This type inherits `foo_validator<>`.
3. The compiler tries to instantiate `foo_validator<>` and finds the exactly-matching specialization, type 2 in the list above.  In the "inherit `foo_validator`" approach, nothing happens and compilation proceeds.  In the `static_assert` approach, this type inherits `std::true_type` and so the assertion succeeds.

Now let's look at a type that should not work: `SomeFunction<Foo<int, int>, std::pair<float, double>>`:

1. The compiler tries to instantiate `foo_validator<Foo<int, int>, std::pair<float, double>>`. This matches the partial specialization, type 3 in the list above.  (`T1 = int, T2 = int, Tail = [std::pair<float, double>]`)  This type inherits `foo_validator<std::pair<float, double>>`.
2. The compiler tries to instantiate `foo_validator<std::pair<float, double>>`. This does not match type 2 or 3 in the list above and so the compiler tries to instantiate the base template declaration (type 1). In the "`foo_validator` approach", this fails because the template type is incomplete (we never defined it). In the `static_assert` approach, the base template is instantiated and inherits `std::false_type`, and so the assertion fails.

Comment: Wow this is some interesting food for thought. Thank you